# Given $a+b+c=abc$, find $\tan^{-1}a+\tan^{-1}b+\tan^{-1}c$.

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with the following problem - a hint of how to approach it would be fine:

> Given $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers and $a+b+c=abc$, find 
>   $$\tan^{-1}(a)+\tan^{-1}(b)+\tan^{-1}(c).$$

Comment: $$\small\tan^{-1}a + \tan^{-1}b + \tan^{-1}c = \begin{cases}
\pi, & 1 < ab+bc+ca \land a + b + c > 0\\
0, & 1 > ab+bc+ca\\
-\pi, & 1 < ab+bc+ca \land a + b + c < 0\end{cases}$$
See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3027564) for argument. Please note that for real $a,b,c$ which satisfies $a+b+c = abc$, it is impossible for $ab+bc+ca = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

By the trigonometric identity
$$
\tan(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) = \frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta+\tan\gamma-\tan\alpha\tan\beta\tan\gamma}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta-\tan\alpha\tan\gamma-\tan\beta\tan\gamma}.
$$
let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be respectively the arctangents of $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that
$$
\frac{a+b+c-abc}{1-ab-ac-bc} = \tan\Big(\arctan(a)+\arctan(b)+\arctan(c)\Big)
$$
then since $a+b+c=abc$ we have that the numerator of the above equation is zero
$$\tan\Big(\arctan(a)+\arctan(b)+\arctan(c)\Big)=0$$
from which we know the tangent function is zero at integer multiples of $\pi$. However, we shouldn't accept all integer values of $\pi$ since $\arctan(\theta):\mathbb R \to (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and therefore the range of $\arctan(\theta)$ is restricted to $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Following the technique shown inside [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027479/tan-1x-tan-1y-tan-1z-tan-1-fracxyz-xyz1-xy-yz-zx-true-fo/3027564#3027564), we may conclude

$$\arctan(a)+\arctan(b)+\arctan(c) = \begin{cases} 
\pi, & 1 < ab+bc+ca ~~\text{and}~~ a+b+c > 0\\
0,   & 1 > ab+bc+ca\\
-\pi & 1 < ab+bc+ca ~~\text{and}~~ a+b+c < 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It's not $\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$ (Instead of $\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$)?

Comment: It is not $[ -\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{\pi}{2}]$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156781/why-is-the-range-of-arctan-frac-pi2-frac-pi2) and remember that the tangent function has vertical asymptotes at integer multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tan^{-1}a=A,a=\tan A$ etc.

For nonzero finite $a,b,c$

Observe that $-\pi/2<A,B,C<\pi/2\implies?<A+B+C<?$

$-c=(a+b)(1-ab)$

$\tan(A+B)=-\tan C=\tan(-C)$

$A+B=n\pi+(-C)$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

Let a=tanA , b= tanB and c= tanC $\\$
Since  tanA + tan B + tan C = tanA.tanB.tanC $\\$
Therefore.  A+B+C= nπ , for n to be any integrr.
And for inverse to define $tan^{-1}x$ lie in interval (-π/2,π/2) $\\$
Hence A+B+C = -π or π

Answer (score 0):

If $A+B+C=n\pi, n \in I ,$ then
$$\tan A+ \tan B + \tan C= \tan A \tan B \tan C$$
So if $\tan A=a, \tan B=b, \tan C=c$, then
$$\tan^{-1} a+\tan^{-1}b.+\tan^{-1} c= n \pi, n\in I.$$

Proof: Let $$A+B+C=n \pi \Rightarrow A+B =n \pi -C \Rightarrow \tan(A+B)=\tan (n \pi-C) \Rightarrow \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1-\tan A \tan B}=-\tan C \Rightarrow \tan A + \tan B+ \tan c= \tan A \tan B \tan C.$$

Interestingly, when a=1, b=2, c=3, then $\tan^{-1} 1+ \tan^{-1} 2 + \tan^{-1} 3= \pi$ is well known.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how you got $A+B+C=n\pi?$

Comment: I understand from the previous posts how we have the substitution $a=\tan A, b=\tan B, c=\tan C,$ and that it follows that $$\tan^{-1}(a)+\tan^{-1}(b)+\tan^{-1}(c)=A+B+C,$$ but I need help on the $n\pi, n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ part.

Comment: It isn't true for all $n\pi, n\in\mathbb Z^+$. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: @guest please see my edit, $n$ ia any integer it need not be positive.